# Nested function returning a variable through the outer function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a requirement which I am going to try an explain through the below example:

Suppose we have a segment of code like this:

```
def a:
    def b:
        x = 2
```

Now I want to return x through the function a. Is there any way to do it in python?

Comment: Yes you can! And if you say how you want to use `a` and `b` I might say how.

Comment: Very strange requirement... What are you _really_ trying to do? Write a decorator maybe?

Comment: whats wrong with `def a: def b: return x (end of b); return b()`?

Comment: If you want to *return* something then why don't you use `return`?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def a():
    def b():
        x = 2 
        return x
    return b()

a()
```